# How can I fetch data from API url into my reactgoogle pie chart in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, rest, ecmascript-6

Here I want to fetch data from a REST API URL which will be fed into the pie chart rather than manually entering data as given in the piechart below.

The API URL will have a JSON response.

**ex:**
[{"Development stage:1,"no.of.project:60},{"Development stage:2,"no.of.project:50}]

I want to display the data on the basis of JSON .

```
                     <Chart
                                  width={'450px'}
                                  height={'310px'}
                                  chartType="PieChart"
                                  loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
                                  data={[
                                    ['Development Stages', 'Number of Project'],
                                    ['Stage 1', 60 ],
                                    ['Stage 2',40],
                                    ['Stage 3',20 ],
                                    ['Stage 4',10],
                                    ['Stage 5', 30],
                                  ]}
                                  options={{
                                    title: 'Projects',
                                  }}
                                  rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1' }}
                    />
```

**How can I use async axios for the same???? and pass it into Chart.**

```
                const [stage,setStage]=useState([]);
                const getStageData = async() => {
              try{

            const data=await axios.get(APIurl
           );

        setStage(data.data)
        }
        catch(e){


        }
    };

    useEffect(()=> {
        getStageData();
    },[]);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using chart.js library?

Comment: I am using reactgoogle chart library

Comment: @ksa can you help me with it?

Comment: please console log "stage" and let me know what do you, see? share that output here.

Comment: @ksa   Yes I have edited the post you can see the log images up there .The stage variable is empty I think.

Comment: are you sure it is empty? if yes, then make sure the stage has the JSON response that you have mentioned above. what do u see when you console log "data.data"? is it empty? if it is not empty then do setStage(...stage , data.data) and then in your chart component do this data = {[stage]}. Not sure if this helps you but give it a try.

Comment: setStage(.data.data), no need for the spread operator here.

Comment: @ksa  In order to covert my array of objects into arrays I used the map(Object.values) as a solution below then after the chart takes appropriate data format. If i dont convert into array using map setStage(data.data) gives me the json object. But in order to display into array format i need to use map but applying it give me empty setStage()

Comment: @ksa   const [stage,setStage]=useState([]);
 const getStageData = async() => {
                    try{
 const data1=await axios.get("url");
setStage(data1.data);
 }
catch(e){}
};
useEffect(()=> {
                            getStageData();
                       },[]);
                
stage.map(Object.values)

This is what my code looks like and c hart it  is ...stage

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. From your code, I can see that you have set the axios response first (setStage(data1.data)), and then you are converting to arrays using stage. map(Object. values). Try to map first and then set state and see. something like this const res = data1.data.map(obejct.values) and then setStage(res).

Comment: @ksa yes I have tried with my solution the data was loading up pretty much did the same as what you told. Once again thankyou so much as i am new to react and only know basics of javascript i was stuck on it, Thanks once again!!!

Comment: No worries. is it working?

Comment: @ksa Yes it is . !!

Comment: I have posted that as an answer. Please accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, the data which you should pass to the pie chart should be array of arrays(depending on the library you are using). Your response data looks like an array of objects.

1. Convert your data to array of arrays.

```
    setStage(reponse.data.map(Object.values));
```

2. Pass that data to the pie chart.

```
    <Chart
       ...otherProps
       data={[
         ['Development Stages', 'Number of Project'], 
         ...data
       ]}
    />
```

Comment: Here the stage is getting converted into array of array but using spread operator it is not display in the chart

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I can see that you have set the axios response first `(setStage(data1.data))`, and then you are converting to arrays using `stage.map(Object. values)`. Try to map first and then set state and see. something like this `const res = data1.data.map(obejct.values)` and then `setStage(res)`.

Answer (score 0):

<Chart width={'450px'} height={'310px'} chartType="PieChart" loader={Loading Chart} data={[['Development Stages', 'Number of Project'],...stage]}options={{title: 'Projects',}}rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1' }} />

Comment: After this also the piechart is coming blank

Answer (score 0):

The Complete working code to use  react-google Piechart along with rest api data call

```
         const [stage,setStage]=useState([]);
         const getStageData = async() => 
        {
             try{

                 const data1=await axios.get("REST_API");

                //converting array of objects into array
                 const res=data1.data.map(Object.values);

                //setting it to stage variable
                setStage(res);  
        }
               catch(e){}  

         }; 
          useEffect(()=> {
                         getStageData();
                            },[]);

    <Chart
         width={'500px'}
         height={'310px'}
         chartType="PieChart"
        loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
        data={[
               ["COLUMN_NAME_1","COLUMN_NAME_2"],
               ...stage
            ]}
       options={{ 
                 title: 'Ongoing Projects Development Stage',                                                                               
               }}
        rootProps={{ 'data-testid': '1'}} 
     />
```